# How to remove reCAPTCHA after phone authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am using phone authentication on Flutter Web like this:

```
  signInWithPhoneNumber(String phone) async {
    try {
      confirmationResult = await _auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phone);
    } catch (e) {
      return onAuthenticationError();
    }
  }
```

Now everything is fine, It's working but in the start, I get the `reCAPTCHA` in the bottom right of the page and it's persistent, not even going after solving `reCAPTCHA`. How do I get rid of it after authentication?

[image]

Comment: I don't know who closed this question but definitely, he did it without reading it.

Comment: I can vote to reopen it. The one who closed it definitely knows about firebase-authentication. :) If you are sure the issue marked as duplicate doesn't solve your problem, then let me know.

Comment: Yeah definitely that's another question. I haven't any issue with `reCAPTCHA` verification, I just want it to be removed after the verification as it's persistent in bottom corner even after the verification.

Comment: a whole year and this issue still exists

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730262/flutter-fireauth-remove-recaptcha-banner-web). Looks like it solves the above issue: