# Flutter FireAuth remove reCAPTCHA banner (WEB)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

I am creating a flutter web app and I am using firebase auth to authenticate users with phone number.

```
await _auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
```

After executing this command, a reCAPTCHA banner appears at the bottom right corner of the page. After completing the reCAPTCHA test, the banner doesn't come off. Even after confirming the sms:

```
await confirmationResult!.confirm(smsCode);
```

[image]

[image]

How can I remove this banner completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apperently it is easy:

```
final el = window.document.getElementById('__ff-recaptcha-container');
if (el != null) {
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: Where do you put this code tho?

Comment: @Manbus put it in the same page where the recaptcha appears, because there you can use the getElementById. if the recaptcha doesn't exists yet then getElementById will fail to find the recaptcha container

Comment: The right answer is what @Vladimir Koltunov mentioned. We have to use `signInWithPhoneNumber`

Answer (score 2):

On web you must call `signInWithPhoneNumber` instead of `verifyPhoneNumber`.

```dart
ConfirmationResult confirmationResult = await auth.signInWithPhoneNumber('+44 7123 123 456');
```

See: [Phone Authentication | Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/phone-auth)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. If you want to confirm verification code use `UserCredential userCredential = await confirmationResult.confirm('123456');`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Put this in index.html

```
<style>
    .grecaptcha-badge { visibility: hidden;}
</style>
```